# The key 'security.user' is not bound to any value in context application

Tags: authentication, authorization, loopback, loopback4

I am new to loopback 4. Currently, I am trying to do the authentication and authorization in my loopback 4 project. I am using the https://github.com/HrithikMittal/loopback4-authorization example as a reference. I was able to generate the JWT token successfully. But I am facing some issues with the authorization part. I have added a new role named  "Manager" which has the provision to get  "UserFeedbackCount".The manager is able to log in successfully. But authorization failed with an error  'security.user' is not bound to any value in context application. Please help me out

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Loopback documentation is not very helpful when it comes to having a step by step on the Authentication and Authorization.

I have a sample project on JWT Authentication with Firebase here. You can read the step by step instructions [here](https://dev.to/alfonsojohan/loopback-4-jwt-authentication-with-firebase-1o4).

I plan to have another step by step for Authorization, hopefully will have it done soon. For now, I can point you on how to move forward. As mentioned in the documentation you need to create a class that implements `Provider<Authorizer>` interface

```
// services/AuthorizationService.ts

@injectable({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
class AuthorizationService implements Provider<Authorizer>{
  // This returns the value to the callee
  value (): Authorizer {
    return this.authorize.bind(this);
  }

  // Implement authorization here
  async authorize (
    context: AuthorizationContext,
    metadata: AuthorizationMetadata,
  ) {
     // TODO implement authorization here
  }
}
```

You then bind the class to the authorization provider key as such in your `application.ts` constructor.

```
// Add this at the bottom of the application.ts constructor
 // bind authorization component to the options and tell which
    // class is the authorization provider
    // then need to tag it as AUTHORIZER
    this.configure(AuthorizationBindings.COMPONENT).to(authorizationOptions);
    this.component(AuthorizationComponent);
    this.bind('authorizationProviders.my-authorizer-provider')
      .toProvider(AuthorizationService)
      .tag(AuthorizationTags.AUTHORIZER);
```

For the **actual** authorization service you can roll out your own or use Casbin as Loopback mentioned in their docs.